# Two array list into one list row (two different textview) in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I have two different `arraylist` for a custom `listview`, how can I make it to come in a single row with two different `textview`. here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.25"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="@7dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_duty_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried making pojo of your array lists?

Comment: Hadn't tried yet.

Comment: You can use pojo to hold your two array list and it is more easier and if you post more code then I can help you lot better

Comment: I will try using pojo and if I have doubt i will text again with more code

Comment: Cool, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Holder class:

```
public class DataHolder {

    private String name,duty_name;

    public DataHolder(String name, String duty_name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duty_name = duty_name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDuty_name() {
        return duty_name;
    }

    public void setDuty_name(String duty_name) {
        this.duty_name = duty_name;
    }
}
```

Array List:

```
ArrayList<DataHolder>list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Base Class:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<DataHolder>list myList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataHolder>list myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.tv_name.setText(currentListData.getName());
        mViewHolder.tv_duty_name.setText(currentListData.getDuty_name());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name, tv_duty_name;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            tv_name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_duty_name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_duty_name);
        }
    }
}
```

layout_list_item:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1.25"
android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="@7dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_duty_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```